# Controlling accuracy for code

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy

So I have a lot of trouble controlling precision and or accuracy with Mathematica. I have tried reading up for it but in the end I get even more confused. Here is my code, it is a little long but it is not complicated:

```
A0 = {{0.8160, -0.3223}, {0.7556, 0.5037}}
B0 = {{-0.0604, 0.9772}, {-0.9168, -0.2619}}
rho = Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[A0.A0.B0.A0.B0.B0]]]^(1/6)
A = A0/rho
B = B0/rho
v[8]=Eigenvectors[B.B.A.B.A.A][[1]]
v[6]=-1.2*Eigenvectors[B.A.B.B.A.A][[1]]
v[12]=A.v[8]
v[3]=B.v[12]
v[16]=A.v[12]
v[7]=B.v[16]
v[10]=A.v[7]
v[14]=A.v[10]
v[5]=B.v[14]
v[1]=B.v[10]
v[9]=A.v[6]
v[13]=A.v[9]
v[4]=B.v[13]
v[11]=-B.v[4]
v[2]=B.v[11]
v[15]=A.v[11]
vertices = Union[Table[v[i], {i, 1, 16}], Table[-v[i], {i, 1, 16}]];
ordering = 
  MeshCells[ConvexHullMesh[Union[vertices, -vertices]], 2][[1, 1]];
orderedvertices = 
  MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[Union[vertices, -vertices]]][[
   ordering]];
S = ConvexHullMesh[Union[vertices], 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Black}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
Max[Table[
   VectorAngle[orderedvertices[[i + 1]] - orderedvertices[[i]], 
    orderedvertices[[i - 1]] - orderedvertices[[i]]], {i, 2, 
    18}]]*180/Pi
images=Union[{B.v[8],A.v[16],B.v[7],A.v[14],A.v[5],B.v[5],A.v[1]},{B.v[6],B.v[9],A.v[13],A.v[4],A.v[2],B.v[2],A.v[15]}]
Max[Table[SignedRegionDistance[S, i], {i, images}]]
```

I need the last two numbers to be accurate to 10 digits. How do I accomplish this? Would making the matrices A0,B0 numbers to say 100 digits suffice?

Comment: One possibility is to use exact input. Use `Rationalize` on your A0, B0 and use 12/10 instead of 1.2. Then at the very end you can always get the accuracy you want using `N[exactValue,nnnn]`

Comment: Most any "ordinary" decimal number that you provide will have $MachinePrecision precision to start with, which is about 16 digits. Calculations can sometimes result in losing some precision.  How much is lost depends on you doing a deep analysis of the exact steps of the calculation. For example, subtracting two almost identical values can give almost zero precision. IF you are certain that you have more precision in your A0 and B0 matricies then you can tell Mathematica that, either by adding trailing zeros or by telling Mathematica that 0.0602`50 has 50 digits of precision. Does that help?

Comment: It'd sure be nice, from my point of view, if unnecessary output were suppressed with semicolons.

Comment: @Nasser I think the rationalization should work thank you. I am still working on it as for some reason working exact precision messes the polygon up. With Machine precision, it is a 32-gon but with exact precision, it is an 18-gon. It's possible this is correct but would seem highly unlikely.

Comment: With infinite precision, eigenvectors are not normalized. With machine precision, they are. Probably explains the difference in the convex hull.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That might be it, I forgot this quirk of the command. Thank you!

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you Micheal and thank you Nasser for your help. I forgot I could do exact precision... Before I was working on something where I could not do exact precision so this simple solution has slipped my mind...